# Microsoft Graph API DeltaLinks for Mailbox messages Not Returning Minimal Data on Changes

Tags: microsoft-graph-api

Delta query on users returns minimal data on changes using the header (***Prefer Return = minimal***).

Graph Explorer : https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users/delta

C# : await graphClient.Users.Request().GetAsync();

But in the case of mailbox messages it returns all parameter, although using the header (***Prefer Return = minimal***).

Graph Explorer : https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users/userid/mailFolders/inbox/messages/delta

C# : await graphClient.Users[userId].MailFolders[folderId].Messages.Delta().Request().GetAsync();

Is there any way to get the minimal data on mailbox message changes with delta query?

Answer (score 1):

The Message delta [documentation](http://Each%20delta%20query%20GET%20request%20returns%20a%20collection%20of%20one%20or%20more%20messages%20in%20the%20response.%20You%20can%20optionally%20specify%20the%20request%20header,%20Prefer:%20odata.maxpagesize=%7Bx%7D,%20to%20set%20the%20maximum%20number%20of%20messages%20in%20a%20response.) only defines a header for limiting the page size:

> Each delta query GET request returns a collection of one or more messages in the response. You can optionally specify the request header, `Prefer: odata.maxpagesize={x}`, to set the maximum number of messages in a response.

If you want to track a specific set of properties, you can limit the response using the [`$Select`](http://Each%20delta%20query%20GET%20request%20returns%20a%20collection%20of%20one%20or%20more%20messages%20in%20the%20response.%20You%20can%20optionally%20specify%20the%20request%20header,%20Prefer:%20odata.maxpagesize=%7Bx%7D,%20to%20set%20the%20maximum%20number%20of%20messages%20in%20a%20response.) query parameter:

> You can use a `$select` query parameter as in any GET request to specify only the properties your need for best performance. The `id` property is always returned.

Only AAD resources support the `Prefer: return=minimal` header.